# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting For a Column

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet that has dates in row 1 and data in the rows below it. I want to highlight the entire column that has a date that is today, or within the last 7 days.

[image: desired outcome]

I've been searching and I keep finding examples of how to highlight a row, but not a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try selecting all cells and: Format - Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is** and:

```
=and(A$1>today()-7,A$1<today()+1)
```

with highlighting of your choice. <kbd>Done</kbd>.

In this case the row is anchored, I agree more usual to anchor (`$`) the column.

Comment: Close. That's highlighting a column, but not the right one. This at least gets me going in the right direction. It highlighted the week of 6/12/2017 instead of 5/29/2017. I think my issue now is it's a pivot table. This gets me what I need though. Thanks!